# Adaptive median filter slows down dramatically shortly after being executed

Tags: python, image-processing, filter

The code below is written for an adaptive method for salt-and-pepper noise removal for the upper left corner of an image. It is a part of the full code for the noise removal algorithm consists of multiple functions - each is meant for individual part of the image, such as upper left corner, upper right corner, upper middle, etc..., and lastly the middle which is the majority of the image.

The algorithm is based on an adaptive approach base on the a method called the Modified Decision Based Partially Trimmed Global Mean Filter (MDBPTGMF).

The code runs and  was tested on a 680x387 image with a probability of 10% of salt-and-pepper noise but after the first 10 seconds, it began to slow down dramatically. After about less than a minute, at around (y,x) == (2, 50),  the speed became barely 1 pixel for every 5 seconds.

I assume it must be the temporary memory that gets filled up and slows down the process. All values in the '#Initialize value' section get replaced or reset after or during the processing of each pixel.

What could potentially be the reasons for the slowing down in speed here?

```
from List import *
from Kernel import *
from pixel_op import *

l = List()
knl = Kernel()
po = pixel_op()

class adaptive_filter:

# Upper left corner
def removeNoise_UpperLeftCorner(self, image):
    fp = None # Filtered pixel value
    w = 3 # Current window size
    w_max = 9 # The maximum window size
    h = 2 # Kernel's increment
    v = [] # The array of elements or pixels of current window
    uv = [] # The array of uncorrupted pixel of current window

    w_max_center = (w_max-1)/2

    for y in range(w_max_center):
        for x in range(w_max_center):

            n = 0 # The number of uncorrupted pixel in current window

            p = po.getGray(image, y, x)# The processing pixel

            gray_mat = knl.getGrayMat_UpperLeftCorner(image, y, x, w) # The kernel with gray values
            v = knl.getGrayListFromGrayMat(gray_mat)

            # If the pixel's value is between 0 and 255, it is identified as an uncorrupted pixel
            # and left unchanged
            if p > 0 and p < 255:
                continue
            else:  
                for i in range(len(v)):
                    if v[i] != 0 or v[i] != 255:
                        uv.append(v[i])
                        n += 1
                if n >= w:
                    median = l.getMed(uv)
                    fp = median
                    po.insertGrayIntoPixel(image, y, x, fp)
                else:
                    while w < w_max and n < w:
                        w += h

                    if w < w_max and n >= w:
                        median = l.getMed(uv)
                        fp = median
                        po.insertGrayIntoPixel(image, y, x, fp)

                    elif w == w_max:
                        gray_mat = knl.getGrayMat_UpperLeftCorner(image, y, x, w_max)
                        v = knl.getGrayListFromGrayMat(gray_mat)

                        if n < w and n != 0:
                            mean = l.getMean(uv)
                            fp = mean
                            po.insertGrayIntoPixel(image, y, x, fp)

                        elif all(p==0 or p==255 for p in v):
                            mean = l.getMean(v)
                            fp = mean
                            po.insertGrayIntoPixel(image, y, x, fp)

                        elif all(p==0 for p in v):
                            fp = 255
                            po.insertGrayIntoPixel(image, y, x, fp)

                        elif all(p==255 for p in v):
                            fp = 0
                            po.insertGrayIntoPixel(image, y, x, fp)
            w = 3 # Reset current window
```

Imported files:
List.py

```
class List:

# Selection sort a list
def sortList(self, list):

    # Selection sort all values in the list
    list_count = len(list)
    for i in range(list_count):
        min = list[i]
        min_j = i

        for j in range(i+1,list_count):
            if list[j] < min:
                min = list[j]
                min_j = j

        # Swap
        temp = list[i]
        list[i] = min
        list[min_j] = temp

    return list

# Return the minimum gray value in the list of gray values
def getMin(self, list):

    # Selection sort the minimum value in the list
    min = list[0]
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        if list[i] <= min:
            min = int(list[i])
        else:
            continue

    return min

# Return the maximum gray value in the list of gray values  
def getMax(self, list):

    # Selection sort the minimum value in the list
    max = list[0]
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        if list[i] >= max:
            max = int(list[i])
        else:
            continue

    return max

def getMean(self, list):
    sum = 0
    list_count = len(list)
    for i in range(list_count):
        sum += list[i]
    mean = sum/list_count
    return mean

# Return the median gray value in the list of gray values
def getMed(self, list):

    sorted_list = self.sortList(list) # The sorted list
    sorted_list_count = len(sorted_list)
    sorted_list_count = int(sorted_list_count) # The number of values in the list

    med = None # The median

    if sorted_list_count % 2 == 0:
        med_pos_1 = int(sorted_list_count/2 - 1)
        med_pos_2 = int(sorted_list_count/2)
        med_1 = float(sorted_list[med_pos_1])
        med_2 = float(sorted_list[med_pos_2])

        med = (med_1 + med_2)/2    
    else:
        med_pos = (sorted_list_count-1)/2
        med = sorted_list[med_pos]

    return med
```

Kernel.py

```
from pixel_op import *

po = pixel_op()

class Kernel:

# Create the kernel of mat_size x mat_size with None values
def getEmptyMat(self, mat_size):
    mat = []  # The kernel

    # Create the kernel
    for j in range(mat_size):  # Number of rows
        mat.append([])
        for i in range(mat_size):  # Number of columns
            mat[j].append(None)       

    return mat

# GET LIST WITH GRAY VALUES
# Upper left corner
def getGrayListFromGrayMat(self, gray_mat):
    gray_list = [] # The list with gray values

    # If the value in the kernel is an integer: add it to the list of gray values
    for i in range(len(gray_mat)):
        for j in range(len(gray_mat[i])):
            if gray_mat[i][j] == None:
                continue
            else:
                gray_list.append(gray_mat[i][j]) 

    return gray_list


# GET KERNEL WITH GRAY VALUES
# Upper left corner
def getGrayMat_UpperLeftCorner(self, image, y, x, mat_size):
    gray_mat = self.getEmptyMat(mat_size) # Empty kernel

    mat_center = (mat_size-1)/2 # The kernel's center position
                                # The potential number of rows/columns outside image

    nrows_outside_image = mat_center-y # The number of rows outside image
    ncols_outside_image = mat_center-x  # The number of columns outside umage

    for i in range(nrows_outside_image, mat_size): # Range of rows in the kernel
        for j in range(ncols_outside_image, mat_size): # Range of columns in the kernel
            # Insert gray value
            gray = po.getGray(image, y-(mat_center-i), x-(mat_center-j))
            gray_mat[i][j] = gray
    return gray_mat
```

pixel_op.py

```
class pixel_op:

# Return gray value of a pixel
def getGray(self, image, y, x):
    try:
        image[y,x,0] == image[y,x,1]
        image[y,x,0] == image[y,x,2]
        image[y,x,1] == image[y,x,2]
    except ValueError:
        print 'The pixel is not in grayscale'

    return image[y,x,0]

# Insert a gray value into a pixel
def insertGrayIntoPixel(self, image, y, x, gray_value):
    #print 'ImageFilter > insertGrayIntoPixel'
    image[y,x] = gray_value
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the likely culprits:

```
    for y in range(w_max_center):
        for x in range(w_max_center):
            ...
            for i in range(len(v)):
            ...
            while w < w_max and n < w:
            ...
            all(p==0 or p==255 for p in v)    # several similar lines
```

It is unclear what the following does, but it might be worth checking its execution times / memory footprint:

```
        p = po.getGray(image, y, x)# The processing pixel

        gray_mat = knl.getGrayMat(image, y, x, w) # The kernel with gray values
        v = knl.getGrayListFromGrayMat(gray_mat)
```

I don't know if it is necessary to call `getGrayListFromGrayMat` 16 times?

Comment: The po.getGray(Image, y,x) is imported from the pixel_op.py (that I have added in the initial description above). image must be in grayscale. Since all values of a pixel are equal to each other in the grayscale BGR pixel, the function returns one value out of the pixel's BGR list (the blue value int his case). p is the gray value of the pixel being processed

Comment: The `knl.getGrayMat(image, y, x, w)` returns a tuple of gray values of the currently being processed pixel `(y,x)`. The value of `(y,x)` is in the middle in a windows size of `w`. It is an adaptive method, so the window size `w` increases accordingly. The maximum window size in this case is 9 (`w_max`)

Comment: The `knl.getGrayListFromGrayMat(gray_mat)` returns a list with only the gray values. In the upper left corner area (or areas that side with the edges of the image in general), part of the kernel will fall out of the image frame more or less. Those "pixels" that fall outside of the the image must not be counted. The `knl.getGrayListFromGrayMat(gray_mat)` ensures that only values inside the image will be returned in a list that will later be used.

Comment: `knl.getGrayMatUpperLeftCorner` calculates how many rows and columns are outside the image at `(y,x)`, and return those outside of image as `None` values. (Please correct the second comment from `knl.getGrayMat(image,y,x,w)` to `knl.getGrayMat_UpperLeftCorner`

Comment: In the area considered to be the 'Upper left corner', the maximum window size will have at least 1 row or 1 column outside of image for any given pixel. The maximum window size here is  `w_max = 9`, hence the size of the area is 4x4=16 pixels. `getGrayListFromGrayMat` is executed each time a pixel is being processed.